# Spock Mock, return "x" when method is called no matter what variables are passed to method

Tags: groovy, spock

So I have a method that has a few variables in its signautre like this `public PageLinksVM mapLinks(URI requestUrl, Integer offset, Integer limit, Integer total)`

If it had no variables on the input I would do the following

```
 def:

object.mapLinks()>> returnedObject
```

How do I do this when the method has inputs and i Want to return no matter what is passed to the method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `*_` to allow any number of any input arguments.

```
def:
  object.mapLinks(*_)>> returnedObject
```

Here is the Spock documentation on [argument contraints](http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_argument_constraints).